# How to escape an entity within jQuery function using jAlert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, escaping, entity

Here's sample code:

```
$("#register-button").click(function(){
    if (uname=="" || pname=="" || cemail=="" || remail=="") {
        jAlert('Please fix the validation error','Title™');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Basically, if username, password, or email fields aren't filled correctly, a jAlert pops up that says "Please fix the validation error" containing a title that's trademarked. Unfortunately, this trademark is not properly an entity and does not render correctly.

I tried the following but it does not work correctly:

```
$("#register-button").click(function(){
    if (uname=="" || pname=="" || cemail=="" || remail=="") {
        jAlert('Please fix the validation error','Title&trade;');
        return false;
    }
});
```

As you can see, the only difference is that I've included **`&trade;`**. However, it does not turn into **™** when the jAlert pops up.

How do I escape the jQuery in order for this entity to properly render?

Comment: are you sure jAlert second argument can use html entities ?

Answer (score 0):

Just define this on function level in your code:

```
String.prototype.htmlEscape = function () {
  return this.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;").replace(/'/g, "&#39;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
}
```

And now you can use it as:

```
jAlert("Please fix the validation error".htmlEscape(),"Title&trade;".htmlEscape());
```

Comment: I'm still new to javascript. Can you explain what you mean by function level? I have entered the first string under the $(document).ready(function(){. Then I replaced my jAlert with your code. But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: in this case answer use prototype not jquery isn't it ?